# Android Double Dash Linux Command Fails

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Am developing Android Cordova app and am using a plugin called **cordova-shell-exec** which simply uses Java **Runtime.getRuntime().exec** method to run Linux shell commands, where all the commands arguments that start with double dash fails but the single dash ones they are working successfully, for example when I run the command **ls -a** then it works, but if I run **ls --all** it does not, I tried to manipulate the plugin Java class and I used Java **ProcessBuilder** instead but it also failed.

Comment: Check with `adb shell`: `which ls`, `ls -l /system/bin/ls` likely points to `toybox`. Check if toybox supports double-dash. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247165/126176

Comment: Correct, I am surprised, I thought Android has a rich Linux distro.